# 's Punctuation in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, adobe

I am trying to add a string with "There's " into the adobe sqlite. and it is indicating there is an error with the  's within the string? Is there anyway i can add 's into SQL statement?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 VALUES(null,"name","There's a string here here",1);
```

Comment: I think you simply escape the `'` with another `'`' i.e. "There''s"

Comment: You need to escape it. That being said, the better practice is to use paramater binding and placeholders. Googling either should point you in the right direction. Example: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_MX_DateField_to_SQLite_query_parameter-18046.html

Comment: You should investigate using prepared statements.

Comment: What, if any, programming language (i.e. php, c# etc) are you using to construct/execute the SQL - Most languages have the ability to perform this sort of escaping for you.

Comment: @MrEyes Some kind of Adobe-based language (see tags). But escaping is the wrong approach in _all_ languages.

Comment: @DonalFellows - And unfortunately, we have yet another programmer who will go on to creating some horrible site open to SQL injection, based on the answer the OP accepted and his comment.

Comment: @MrEyes i am using Flex [ actionscript in flashbuilder ] with adobe build in DB which is sqlite and i am using the API [SQLite Manager][1] to use multiple tables, transactions and rollbacks. 


  [1]: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_AIR_SQLite_Manager_API_allow_using_multiple_tables-16126.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 VALUES(null,'name','There''s a string here here',1);
```

Answer (score 2):

While you *can* simply escape the `'` the better practice is to use parameter binding and placeholders; SQL injection is not your friend.

```
stmt.text = "INSERT INTO PERSON (FNAME, LNAME) " 
            + "values(:FNAME, :LNAME)";

stmt.parameters[":FNAME"] = edtFName.text;
stmt.parameters[":LNAME"] = edtLName.text;

...

<s:TextInput id="edtFName" />
<s:TextInput id="edtLName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all apostrophies in strings with two consecutive apostrophies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310577/how-to-insert-statements-that-contains-apostrophe-s-into-sqlite-database) (iPhone instead of Adobe) is that you must either **add a second apostrophe to every apostrophe** ( "There's" becomes "There''s") or you use parameterized SQL statements.