# How to insert a name with apstrophe in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to insert `Gandhi's Salt March` as the Name in the Name column of my database. I have the following function to detect apostrophes in names and capitalize the starting character:

```
public static String toTitleCase(String givenString) {
        StringBuffer sb = null;
        if(givenString.contains("'")){
            givenString = givenString.replace("'", "\\'"); 
            System.out.println("Replace: "+givenString);
            
        }
        try{
            String[] arr = givenString.split("\\s+");
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(0))).append(arr[i].substring(1)).append(" ");
            }          
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
        System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
```

The first System.out.println() results in the following:

```
Replace: Gandhi\'s Salt March
```

In SQLite I get the following exception:

```
(1) near "s": syntax error
From catch 2android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Details (BirthDate, Name);
```

What is going wrong here?

#### Edit:

After using the escape char as `''` I still get an unwanted apostrophe  in the name:

[image]

Comment: NO: `givenString = givenString.replace("'", "\\'");` YES: `givenString = givenString.replace("'", "''");`. If you use bound parameters (**?**) in your query, this **MUST NOT** be done (binding will automatically take care of all the apostrophes in strings).

Comment: Hey @DerGolem my friend, I worked on your second solution and it works uber!! Thanks for being the savior!

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, for future users having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong: `givenString = givenString.replace("'", "\\'");`
Right: `givenString = givenString.replace("'", "''");`

Note: If you use bound parameters (**?**) in your query, this **MUST NOT** be done (binding will automatically manage all the apostrophes in string values).

Comment: I also love your display picture!

Comment: It's from an old movie about me... ;)

Comment: Share the movie name mate!!

Comment: `Der Golem, wie er in die Welt kam` (The Golem, how he came into the World), 1920. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZO_Kd3kkwE

Comment: Going to watch it tonight!! Thanks once again matey :)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this if it helps:

```
givenString = givenString.replace("'", "''");
```

**NOTE:**

Don't rely upon `System.out.println("Replace: "+givenString);` because it's **Java** which is **treating the character differently than SQLite**, you should just checkout the value inserted in your **Database**.

Comment: I just checked it in my Listview I get the entry as `Gandhi''s Salt March` with the technique you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Put 2 single qoutes.

**QUERY**

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES('Gandhi''s Salt March');
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: That leads to an extra unwanted apostrophe in the name: `Gandhi''s Salt March`

Comment: In the `insert` query , one single quote is to escape the other one. See the result which I got in the shell.`Gandhi's Salt March`.

Comment: Give me a moment, I will just update the screen capture of my listview which comes from the Database

Comment: I have checked in the database and your suggestion is correct!! I have it as `Gandhi's Salt March` in the database. However I dont know what is inserting the extra apostrophe in the Listview

Comment: Then replace `''` with `'`. Eg: `givenString = givenString.replace("''","'");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71308/discussion-between-user3-and-ullas).

Answer (score 1):

You should either use parameterized SQL queries just as Ignacio suggested OR you have to replace each ' with ''

```
 Insert into tbl_insert values ('It is Steve''s Shirt');
```

you can find more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310577/how-to-insert-statements-that-contains-apostrophe-s-into-sqlite-database)